# Trying to build a Screen flow that launches an Invocable Apex Class with a Fault Path

Tags: apex, validation-rule, lead-conversion, screen-flow

I built a record triggered flow to launch an invocable Apex class that auto converts leads. The problem is their are several validation rules on the lead object so whenever a user converts a lead that violates one of the validation rules instead of getting a useful error from the validation rule they get a confusing message saying that the flow failed which is confusing them.

To get around this I want to create a screen flow that launches the Apex with a fault path from the Apex action but I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to do this. Any advise?

Specifically how should I launch the process? Should I use a quick action to launch the flow on the convert button? Also, is there a way to modify the fault path so I can include a message specific to the validation rule they are violating?

[image]

Here is a picture of what I have so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you're going about this the wrong way. You can simply return a value to the flow to determine the path:

```
public class Request {
  @InvocableVariable(required=true) public Lead record;
}
public class Result {
  @InvocableVariable public Boolean success;
  @InvocableVariable public String message;
}
@InvocableMethod(label='Auto Convert Leads')
public static Result[] autoConvertLeads(Request[] requests) {
  Result[] results = new Result[0];
  Lead[] leadsToConvert = new Lead[0];
  for(Request request: requests) {
    leadsToConvert.add(request.record);
  }
  // I'm abstracting this away here
  Database.LeadConvert[] converts = setupLeadConverts(leadsToConvert);
  // Allow partial success here
  Database.LeadConvertResult[] convertResults = Database.convertLeads(converts, false);
  for(Database.LeadConvertResult leadConvertResult: convertResults) {
    Result res = new Result();
    res.success = leadConvertResult.isSuccess();
    if(!res.success) {
      res.message = res.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
    }
    results.add(res);
  }
  return results;
}
```

You'd then get rid of the fault screen, and instead use a Decision Element to show the error when success is false, and the final screen when success is true.